# TypeError: unorderable types: int() > NoneType()

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-conversion, nonetype

The algorithm problem [No.188: Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock IV](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-iv/).

*Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price of a given stock on day i.*

*Design an algorithm to find the maximum profit. You may complete at most k transactions.*

*Note:You may not engage in multiple transactions at the same time (ie, you must sell the stock before you buy again).*

---

The following code is the solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Solution:
    # @param {integer} k
    # @param {integer[]} prices
    # @return {integer}
    def maxProfit(self, k, prices):
        size = len(prices)
        if k >= size/2:
            return self.quickSolve(size, prices)
        profit = [ None ]*(2*k+1)
        profit[0] = 0
        for i in range(size):
            for j in range(min(2*k, i+1), 0, -1):
                profit[j] = max(profit[j], profit[j-1]+prices[i]*[1, -1][j%2]) 
        return max(profit)
    def quickSolve(self, size, prices):
        sum = 0
        for x in range(size-1):
            if prices[x+1] > prices[x]:
                sum += prices[x+1]-prices[x]
        return sum
```

This solution is working fine if I submit it on the Leetcode.

However, in my terminal, it gives the following error:

```
 File "best_time_to_buy_and_sell_stock_IV.py", line 26, in maxProfit
    profit[j] = max(profit[j], profit[j-1]+prices[i]*[1, -1][j%2]) 
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > NoneType()
```

This may because I am using **python3** and ***None*** cannot be compared with ***int***, whereas ***profit*** is initialized as ***None***.

But why it is working on Leetcode test?   And how can I make it work under python3?

Thanks~

Comment: You could  `profit = [float("-inf") ]*(2*k+1)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah.   It works.   Thank you.    So does that mean in python2.x, when None is compare with integer, None is regarded as -infinity?

Comment: No it just means None and ints can be compared in python 2 just like strings and ints can but python 3 raises an error. No value will be less than `-inf` so you are safe getting the max